# Implement a trait for a trait in Rust?

Tags: rust, traits

I am trying to build a math library and I have a trait `Matrix<T>` that specific implementations (`struct`) will implement. But I want to provide as much functionality within the `Matrix` trait. For instance, by defining `Index<(usize,usize), Output=T>` I am able to access all fields of the matrix. This makes it easy to implement functionality such as `Add`, `Sub` or `Display`.

But when I try something like this:

```
trait Matrix<T> : Display {

  fn fmt(...) {...}
}
```

Rust does not recognize `fmt` as an implementation of `Display`. So when I do

```
struct MatrixImpl{}

impl Matrix for MatrixImpl{}
```

It wants me to define `fmt` for `MatrixImpl` even though `Matrix` already provides that. This is a bit baffling to me. Also `impl Display for Matrix` doesn't work, because now Rust wants to resort to trait objects, i.e. `impl Display for dyn Matrix` even though that won't work because `Matrix` is not gonna be a trait object due to all the generics in it. And even if it was, it's not zero cost abstraction. Of course then `impl<T,M:Matrix<T>> Display for M` also won't work lol. It's a mess.

I understand in some variants of this problem, this could cause issues, but I do not understand why Rust doesn't simply use the `fmt` function on `Matrix` and uses whatever more specific method is available to override that. Like sure, there could be conflicts. But these are very trivial to resolve because any method implemented on a trait are just `defaults`, meaning if ever anything more specific is in conflict, you just pick the more specific implementation.

What I want is to have a couple very fundamental operations like `new`, `row_count`, `indexing`, etc. be implemented by every implementation of `Matrix`, but then I want all the dozens of default implementations and behaviour to automatically be available to all implementors. If a specific implementation, like TensorFlow has more efficient variants, they can override them. But when you implement your own matrix, at least you won't be faced with having to provide 100 implementations for all the common traits shared by all matrices. But instead, you can gradually improve it as you override and specialize default behaviour.

Comment: When you declare `Display` a supertrait of `Matrix`, you don't need to include `fmt()` in `Matrix`; Every `Matrix` must also implement `Display`, and you can access the `fmt()` of `Display`.

Comment: Yeah, but that's exactly what I don't want. I want to implement `Display` in `Matrix` so that anyone who implements `Matrix` doesn't have to, unless they wanna override the default implementation I provided.

Comment: Normally, you would provide a blanket implementation `impl<T: Matrix> Display for T`, but since you don't own `Display`, you cannot do that. You can provide a macro to ease the implementation.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why Rust wouldn't allow this? Maybe this needs an RFC then, because really the triple whammy of also not allowing `impl<T: Matrix> Display for T` makes it impossible to do this simple thing without macros. Writing macros for this is possible, however it is also problematic because then you create actual conflicts and it's probably not possible anymore to override these methods selectively unless you have one macro for each method.

Comment: It disallow this since no one can promise you won't implement both `Matrix` and `Display` for your type. I'm not saying there is no way it could be allowed, and if you have ideas you are welcomed to propose an RFC, but this will have to include serious design work and motivation.

Comment: Right, but that isn't really a problem because Rust knows that the `fmt` in `Matrix` actually implements `Display`. I.e. implementing `Matrix` will not entail implementing `fmt`, but it *could*. But I agree there is a bunch of preference rules to evaluate. Generally I believe this is all easy to resolve because this `default` implementation will simply *always* be discarded in favour of anything else that is there. I.e. the compiler will check for this function only before emitting the compilation error that `Display` is in fact not implemented but now see this method and succeed instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256972/discussion-between-chayim-friedman-and-mara).

Answer (score 0):

The one thing you can't do in Rust is use `Display::fmt` if `Display` is implemented, otherwise use something else. You are required to disambiguate, at some point, which one you want to use.

But you can make it extremely simple for implementers and users of your trait to use one or the other. What I've done is adapt the idea of [`Path::display`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.display) to work on your trait. [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=28b2280e23a1c7c219cb03782d6e8c62)

```rust
use std::fmt::{self, Display};
use std::marker::PhantomData;

pub trait Matrix<T> {
    fn dimensions(&self) -> [usize; 2];

    fn items<'a>(&'a self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &'a T> + 'a
    where
        T: 'a;

    // Default impl that uses the other functions to print
    fn fmt_matrix(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result
    where
        T: Display,
    {
        let [x, y] = self.dimensions();
        let mut iter = self.items();
        write!(f, "[")?;
        for _row in 0..y {
            write!(f, "[ ")?;
            for item in iter.by_ref().take(x) {
                write!(f, "{item} ")?;
            }
            writeln!(f, "]")?;
        }
        write!(f, "]")
    }

    // Function for conveniently retrieving an impl Display
    fn display(&self) -> MatrixDisplay<'_, Self, T> {
        MatrixDisplay(self, PhantomData)
    }
}

// Wrapper struct whose only purpose is to forward Display::fmt to Matrix::fmt_matrix
pub struct MatrixDisplay<'a, M: ?Sized, T>(&'a M, PhantomData<T>);

impl<'a, M, T> Display for MatrixDisplay<'a, M, T>
where
    M: Matrix<T> + ?Sized,
    T: Display,
{
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        self.0.fmt_matrix(f)
    }
}

// Example implementer that also implements Display
pub struct EmptyMatrix<T>(PhantomData<T>);

impl<T> Display for EmptyMatrix<T> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "[]")
    }
}

impl<T> Matrix<T> for EmptyMatrix<T> {
    fn dimensions(&self) -> [usize; 2] {
        [0, 0]
    }

    fn items<'a>(&'a self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &'a T> + 'a
    where
        T: 'a,
    {
        std::iter::empty()
    }

    // Overriding when the type implements Display is very simple
    fn fmt_matrix(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result
    where
        T: Display,
    {
        self.fmt(f)
    }
}
```